# Efficiently seperate a portion of an array based on the range of another when arrays are very large

Tags: python, arrays, performance, bigdata

I have two sets of numpy arrays: x1,y1 and x2,y2. I want to keep all x1 and y1 values that have matching y coordinates in the y2 array. We can assume all the y2 values are present in the y1 array.

e.g.

```
x1 = [5,6,7,8,9,0] 
y1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
x2 = [5,4,3,2] 
y2 = [2,3,4,5]

#as y2 values 2,3,4,5 are present in y1, I want the output to be:
x1 = [6,7,8,9] y1 = [2,3,4,5]
```

All output arrays are therefore the same size, and have the same y coordinates.

I can do it using the following code. However, the arrays I want to work with have sizes > 100k making this very very slow and inefficient. Is there a better way to do this? Speed and efficiency is my main goal, if I learn a better method then its a bonus! Thanks in advance!!

```
x1 = [5,6,7,8,9,0]
y1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

x2 = [11,12,13,14]
y2 = [2,3,4,5]

max1 = max(y2)
min1 = min(y2)

for i, y in enumerate(y1):
    if (y >= min1) and (y <= max1):
        print (x1[i],y)
```

Comment: when you talk about "matching" y coordinates, your code just checks whether `min(y2) <= y1 <= max(y2)` and you're not likely to do much better than the code you already have for the actual matching.  the efficiencies to be gained are probably elsewhere.  i.e. getting the data in/out better

Comment: What do you mean by matching? The expected output of y1 can be achieved simply by `print(set(y2).intersection(set(y1)))`. Cannot understand the x1 output

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I may be misleading with my mini example. It was rough code i threw in as I wanted to show that i can iterate through each value in the arrays (which I don't want to do as the arrays I want to use are big). I was hoping for a solution that would return all values in an array that had matching values in my reference array in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy](https://readthedocs.org/projects/numpy/) for performance. Find matching indices in one pass where two list are same and slice the numpy array using those matching indices

```
import numpy as np
x1 = [5,6,7,8,9,0] 
y1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y2=[2,3,4,5]
x2_indices=[i for i, item in enumerate(y1) if item in y2] #[1, 2, 3, 4]
x2=np.array(x1)[x2_indices]
print(x2,y2) #(array([6, 7, 8, 9]), [2, 3, 4, 5])
```

If looking for one liner and should be faster than previous one(not tested yet)

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array(x1)[np.nonzero(np.in1d(y1, y2))[0]]) #[6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: One liner works for me, thanks! I will be doing more speed testing with it but it appears np.isin() is recommended over np.in1d(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([5,6,7,8,9,0])
y1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
x2 = np.array([5,4,3,2])
y2 = np.array([2,3,4,5])

elements = np.array([item for item in y2 if item in y1])
idxs = [np.where(y1 == item)[0][0] for item in elements]

print(x1[idxs], elements)
```

**Output:**

```
[6 7 8 9] [2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is much appreciated, works well for the arrays I have.